# Using mongo_dart, how can I query with $in: []

Tags: mongodb, dart

From [mongodb manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/):

```
db.inventory.find( { type: { $in: [ 'food', 'snacks' ] } } )
```

How can I do the same with mongo_dart?
The dart editor doesn't like "$in", and with an escape "\$in" I don't get any hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `db.inventory.find(where.oneFrom('type', [ 'food', 'snacks' ])`

You can also have a look to [this example](https://github.com/sdeleuze/opensnap-polymer/blob/master/os-user/lib/user_service.dart#L23) from my OpenSnap sample application.

Comment: Hi, Sebastien. I believe your answer is correct but I have some deliberation about code in your example. Namely - you are using string values for _id's of your objects. It may be OK if you are doing that deliberately for some valid reasons, but generally speaking it is not best way to store objects in mongodb. I mean external tools can be confused and so on.